# Write the PDF of an exponential prior given E[$\theta$] = 2

Tags: gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, conjugate-prior

I am reviewing old exercise solutions and the following info is given:
Assume that the conjugate prior for θ (as a special case of the gamma distribution) is following the exponential distribution with E[θ] = 2.

When finding the posterior they've used a prior proportional to $\exp(-\frac{1}{2} \theta)$. How does one conclude that?

From wikipedia I find that:
[image]

Comment: An exponential distribution with mean $2$ has rate $\frac12$ and density $\frac12\exp(-\frac12 x)$.  Th question says this is the prior distribution for $\theta$ and uses the word "proportional"

Comment: I see, so the 1/2 infront of the exp() is noted as a constant and thus not affecting $\theta$. Thank you very much! :)